# Is there any way to rig/hack the aperture wide open on a Nikon G lens so I can use it on a 35mm film camera?

Tags: nikon, aperture, tamron

I have a [(Tamron 17-50 f/2.8 with VC)](http://www.dpreview.com/news/0909/09090107tamron17mm50mm.asp) and Nikon FM2 film camera.

I'm aware that the image circle on this lens isn't large enough for the 35mm film and I'm not worried about that. The only thing stopping me from using this lens on this camera is that the camera has no aperture control for it, so if I were to take a picture it would be at f/32.

Is there any sort of lens hack, destructive or non-destructive, which I can perform to lock the aperture wide open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bjørn Rørslett](http://www.naturfotograf.com/index2.html) solved this problem by just jamming a few match-sticks into the aperture control lever of a lens

[[image]

link](http://www.naturfotograf.com/summer_mad.html)

It's crude as hell, but apparently it worked well enough for a weekend.
Really, anything relatively clean, which is softer then the aperture lever (e.g. plastic, wood) would be effective.

<sup>I'm borrowing the picture from his site. I hope he doesn't mind</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Well aperture is controlled by a little spring loaded lever on the mount side of the lens - *theoretically* you could have some kind of ring like an extension tube that would allow for manual aperture control.  However, increasing that distance would cause the lens to lose infinity focus unless there was an additional optical element in the ring to correct it.

I'm not aware of any existing product like this - the additional optical element would degrade some quality.  It's definitely not anything you could DIY at any reasonable cost.